# help with rearrangement of leibniz sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence: $$1 -\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}...$$
How can I find a new arrange of this sequence so this sequence doesn't converge at all?(even to $-\infty ,\infty $)

So far I noticed that is Leibniz so *this* arrangement makes the sequence converge. I thought about putting brackets but I'm not sure I can even do it.can someone help me? tnx!

Comment: Add positive terms until you just exceed $1$. Subtract negative terms until just you drop below $0$. Add positive terms until you just exceed $1$. Subtract negative terms until you just drop below $0$. Continue...

Comment: @DavidMitra what do you mean by "adding positive terms"?

Comment: E.g., start with $1$. Then subtract: $1 -1/2-1/4 -1/6 -1/8$ ($<0$). Then add terms $1/3, 1/5,1/7,\ldots$ until the total sum so far exceeds or equals $1$ again. (In my previous comment, the "positive terms" are $1$, $1/3$, $\ldots$. The "negative terms" are $1/2$, $1/4$, $\ldots$. Admittingly, the phrase "subtract negative terms" is bad...)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the rearrangement which starts
$$1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{17}-\cdots\ .$$
The first partial sum is $1$; the fifth is $-\frac{1}{24}$ which is less than $0$; the thirteenth is $\frac{6364777}{6126120}$ which is greater than $1$.  We will then continue with the even denominators, subtracting $\frac{1}{10}$ and so on until the partial sum is again less than $0$: this must happen eventually because the infinite sum
$$-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{14}-\cdots$$
diverges to $-\infty$ and therefore must at some stage be less than $-\frac{6364777}{6126120}$.  Then we will add odd terms to get above $1$ again, and so on.  The partial sums of the series oscillate between values just below zero and just above $1$, and so the series diverges.  Because of the way we have constructed the series, every term in the original series will be included exactly once.

Comment: tnx a lot!.@David Mitra i guess you meant to this answer, tnx you to!